# Two authentication services in a single application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have an application that authenticates the login against the Microsoft Active Directory, but now I need that if the user is not in the AD of the organization, try to authenticate against an OpenLDAP directory, is it possible with spring-boot in a single application?

How can I indicate in the configuration class that there are two providers to authenticate? Or, do I have to use a handler or similar to perform double authentication?

My code is similar to the following with its own filters and some changes, but the scheme is similar.
Code source: https://medium.com/@dmarko484/spring-boot-active-directory-authentication-5ea04969f220

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigAD extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

 @Value("${ad.domain}")
 private String AD_DOMAIN;

 @Value("${ad.url}")
 private String AD_URL;

 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

  http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
 }

 @Override
 protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
      authManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()).userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
 }

 @Bean
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
     return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider()));
 }
 @Bean
 public AuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider() {
     ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider provider = new ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider(AD_DOMAIN, AD_URL);
     provider.setConvertSubErrorCodesToExceptions(true);
     provider.setUseAuthenticationRequestCredentials(true);
     return provider;
 }
}
```

Comment: You need to write a custom AuthenticationManager

Answer (score 0):

I am also doing the same in my application:

- Authenticate against the LDAP
- Authenticate against the database.

First of all LDAP server is already set up.
So in application.properties file we have all the information required to connect to the LDAP server and **a Boolean field to check whether we want to authenticate against LDAP server or not.**

```
project.ldap.server.protocol=
project.ldap.server.host.name=
project.ldap.server.ip=
project.ldap.server.port=
project.ldap.service.url=
project.ldap.authentication=(false/true)
```

A service which will perform the authentication against the LDAP server

```
@Service
public class LDAPAuthenticationConnectorService {

    @Value("${project.ldap.server.protocol}")
    private String LDAP_SERVER_PROTOCOL;

    @Value("${project.ldap.server.ip}")
    private String LDAP_SERVER_IP;

    @Value("${project.ldap.server.port}")
    private int LDAP_SERVER_PORT;

    @Value("${project.ldap.service.url}")
    private String LDAP_SERVICE_URL;

    /**
     * 
     * @param loginDto
     * @throws ADAuthenticationException
     */
    public String authenticate(LoginDto loginDto) throws ADAuthenticationException{//logic }
```

Now in FacadeImplementation you can do as following:

```
 public class LoginFacadeImpl implements LoginFacadeInt {
       @Value("${project.ldap.authentication}")
        private Boolean isProjectLDAPAuthenticationEnabled;
    @Override
        public UserDto authenticateUser(String userName, String password) {
    try {
                authenticateViaLDAP(userName, password);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                //do authetication against database
                UserEntity userEntityForAuthentication = 
                UserManagementDaoInt.authenticateUser(userName,
                        AuthenticationUtils.convertPasswordToSha256(password));
}
```

Hope this helps:)
Let me know:)

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution.

> Spring Security supports a wide range of authentication mechanisms. AuthenticationManagerBuilder object allows using multiple built-in authentication provider like In-Memory authentication, LDAP authentication, JDBC based authentication. In addition to its own set of authentication models, Spring Security allows to write your custom authentication mechanism to authenticate, for example, against a secure RESTful or SOAP remote API  authentication service.

Link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-multiple-auth-providers

The following example shows how to put two authentication providers, one in a row from another. One: in memory, and other: customAuthentcationProvider.

- auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
- auth.inMemoryAuthentication()

Example:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MultipleAuthProvidersSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter                     {
@Autowired
CustomAuthenticationProvider customAuthProvider;

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) 
  throws Exception {

    auth.authenticationProvider(customAuthProvider);
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("memuser")
        .password(encoder().encode("pass"))
        .roles("USER");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/**")
        .authenticated();
}


@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
}
```